# Create dynamically expandable Goupbox in MFC and place the controls with in it

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, groupbox

I want to create 2 Groupboxes placed one below another in dialog and place some control items with in both Groupboxes. The number of controls with in the Group boxes decided on run time.

The Groupbox size should be fit to the number of controls with in it and second Groupbox should be next to first Groupbox.

Answer (score 0):

Create the groupbox dynamically - at run time . This http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/2004-07/2144.html might be helpful and add the controls during runtime, making the group box the parent window .

Comment: Pretty sure the groupbox should be a sibling, not a parent. Groupbox has a transparent center but is not the parent of the controls inside.